# Identify unwrapped mesh UV regions

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex, uv-mapping

suppose we have a 3D mesh with texture coords for each vertex, so if I render it unwrapped I get something like this (ignore the red square):

[image]

Now I'm trying to find the proper algorithm to uniquely identify those regions using the vertex UVs and storing an attribute with this unique id value. The idea is to use this value as an index for a color table and get something like this (hand made):

[image]

I tried iterating each vertex and finding "unconnected" triangles comparing texture coords, but the mesh indices order seems unrelated to how UVs are placed or i'm not applying the correct formula. I have no doubts about how to store and pass this value to a shader or whatever, the doubt is how to know the "region" to which the vertex belongs, or ultimately, the pixel.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
The data used to render the mesh is a list of vertices (GL_VERTEX_BUFFER) plus a list of indices (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY). The mesh is rendered as GL_TRIANGLES, and each vertex is a struct like this:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
    float tcx, tcy;
    float regionId; //the attribute I want to fill
};

struct MPUVRegionVertex
{
    float x, y;
    int faceId, regionId;
};
```

UPDATE 2: I created a new vertex array of MPUVRegionVertex, with an element for each index (not per unique vertex). Following @CsabaBálint response I ended up with this code:

```
MPUVRegionVertex* uvVertexData = new MPUVRegionVertex[indexCount];

for(int ic = 0; ic < indexCount / 3; ic++)
{
    for(int vc = 0; vc < 3; vc++)
    {
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].x = vertexData[indexData[3*ic+vc]].tcx;
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].y = vertexData[indexData[3*ic+vc]].tcy;
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].faceId = ic;
    }
}

std::vector<std::forward_list<int> > graph(indexCount);

for(int t1=0;t1 < indexCount; ++t1)
{
    for(int t2 = t1 + 1; t2 < indexCount; ++t2)
    {
        if (uvVertexData[t1].faceId == uvVertexData[t2].faceId)
        {
            graph[t1].push_front(t2);
            graph[t2].push_front(t1);
        }
    }
}

std::forward_list<int> stack;
std::vector<int> component(indexCount);
std::set<int> notvisited;

for(int nv = 0; nv < indexCount; nv++)
{
    notvisited.insert(nv);
}


int k = 0;
while(notvisited.size() > 0)
{
    stack.push_front(*notvisited.begin());
    notvisited.erase(notvisited.begin());

    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        //SOMETHING WRONG HERE
        int temp = stack.front();
        notvisited.erase(temp);
        stack.pop_front();
        component[temp] = k;
        stack.merge(graph[temp]);
        graph[temp].clear();
    }
    k++;
}
```

The result is a different k every three indexes, this means that k++ is called for each new triangle, so I'm missing something in the algorithm :S.

```
component[0]=0
component[1]=0
component[2]=0
component[3]=1
component[4]=1
component[5]=1
component[6]=2
component[7]=2
component[8]=2
component[9]=3
...
component[1778]=592
component[1779]=593
component[1780]=593
component[1781]=593
```

Some information about the mesh:

```
Size of shape[0].indices: 1782
shape[0].positions: 1242
shape[0].texcoords: 828
shape[0].normals: 1242
```

**UPDATE 3**

For more information, there is only one UV coord for each vertex.

Deductions / Rules up to now:

- a vertex can be in most than one face (part of more than one triangle).
- a vertex will be n times in the vertexToFace array, once per face it belongs.
- first vertex in the vertexToFace array will arbitrary have regionId = 0.
- a vertex belongs to a region if it shares the same x and y coords or the same face of another vertex in that region.

If I understood well, this is the correct information to implement the non-recursive graph traversal. I need to iterate and save both connected and unconnected vertex, all connected vertex will be part of the current region, all not will be checked again with the already connected, the first iteration stores the first triangle vertexes, the second one stores all vertexes of triangles that are "touching" the first triangle, continue until an iteration gives no new connected vertex (optimization here if we check only with the list of vertex added in the last iteration), no new vertex added means it's time to increment the regionId and start again with the first unconnected vertex.

I will try to implement the search following that design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following the previously mentioned points and thanks to Csaba Bálint for the initial hints, I found a solution:

```
MPUVRegionVertex* uvVertexData = new MPUVRegionVertex[indexCount];

for(int ic = 0; ic < indexCount / 3; ic++)
{
    for(int vc = 0; vc < 3; vc++)
    {
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].x = vertexData[indexData[3*ic+vc]].tcx;
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].y = vertexData[indexData[3*ic+vc]].tcy;
        uvVertexData[3*ic+vc].faceId = ic;
    }
}

std::set<int> notAssigned;

for(int nv = 0; nv < indexCount; nv++)
{
    notAssigned.insert(nv);
}

std::forward_list<int> addedInLastIterationElements;
int currentRegion = 0;

//while there are not assigned vertex 
while (notAssigned.size() > 0)
{
    //the first not assigned element simulate that was "added" to the current region in the last check
    addedInLastIterationElements.push_front(*notAssigned.begin());

    //this first has the new current region as it's regionId
    uvVertexData[*notAssigned.begin()].regionId = currentRegion;

    //and becomes assigned
    notAssigned.erase(notAssigned.begin());

    do
    {
        //will store the elements added in the next iteration
        std::forward_list<int> newRegionElements;

        //iterate not assigned elements
        for(int currentElement : notAssigned)
        {
            //iterate elements added to the current region in the last iteration
            for(int currentRegionElement : addedInLastIterationElements)
            {
                //compare if this vertex belongs to the same region of some of the recently added
                if((uvVertexData[currentElement].x == uvVertexData[currentRegionElement].x && 
                    uvVertexData[currentElement].y == uvVertexData[currentRegionElement].y) ||
                   (uvVertexData[currentElement].faceId == uvVertexData[currentRegionElement].faceId))
                {
                    //store as an element added this iteration
                    newRegionElements.push_front(currentElement);

                    //store the current region
                    uvVertexData[currentElement].regionId = currentRegion;
                }
            }
        }

        //remove new elements from the notAssigned list
        for(int assigned : newRegionElements)
        {
            notAssigned.erase(assigned);
        }

        //replace the elements added the previous iteration for the last iteration
        addedInLastIterationElements = newRegionElements;

        //prepare for new elements
        newRegionElements.clear();
    }
    //if there is no match in the last iteration, means all remaining vertex belongs to another region
    while(!addedInLastIterationElements.empty());

    //next region
    currentRegion++;
}
```

If a render the regionId generated with a table of colors I get the desired result (note that colors varies only in 0.1 per channel, but here are 10 different colors):

[image]

Sure the algorithm can be optimized but it performs in a reasonable time and memory usage, so, for now it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm trying to find the proper algorithm to uniquely identify those regions using the vertex UVs and storing an attribute with this unique id value.

**Creating a graph**

Make ids for the vertexes and the faces (number them). But make sure the same vertexes get the same id-s, compare them by UV or position.

Create a vector: `std::vector<int> vertexToFace;`

The `vertexToFace[i]==j` means i th vertex is on face j.

Then two vertexes are neighbours if they are on the same face.

Then create an  `std::vector<std::forward_list<int> > graph;` Store the vertexes as vector index, and add the neighbours. (O(n^2) complexity)

To do this, you must take the i th vertex, and for every j you have to check weather they are on the same face. A bit optimized version:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) for(int j=i+1; j <n ++j)
if (vertexToFace[i] == vertexToFace[j])
{
    graph[i].push_front(j);
    graph[j].push_front(i);
}
```

This is O(n^2) but it is easy to implement. A harder but faster one requires another vector: `std::vector<std::array<int,3>> faceToVertex;`, this way, from i th vertex you can access its neighbours in constant time. Either way, we have built a graph in which we are looking for [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)), which is easy with [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

**Implementing connected components algorithm**

To implement this, you have to make another vector: `std::vector<bool> visited(n,false);`, and another one `std::vector<int> component(n)`. The solution to your problem will be in this last one.

The algorithm is simple, start from vertex 0, and set `visited[0] = true;` and `component[0]=0;`. Then for each unvisited neighbour do exactly the same, so for neighbour i (some element of the forward_list) `if (!visited[i]) component[i] = 0;`, then do the same. It stops when all element of the component becomes visited. So then you have to look for an unvisited element, and do the above again, but know you are doing component 1, and so on. Example:

```
int l, k=0;
while(l!=n)
{
    l=0;
    while(visited[l]) l++;
    fill_from(graph, visited, component, l, k);
    ++k;
}
```

I think you get the idea, so: (pseudo code)

```
void fill_from(graph, visited, component, l, k)
{
    if(visited[l]) return;
    component[l] = k;
    for(auto &i : graph[l])
            fill_from(graph,visited,component,i,k);
}
```

Then we are done with the task, but this is not yet the fastest solution.

**Faster algorithm**

To get even faster, we have to get rid of the recursion and we do not need the graph afterwards, use a `std::forward_list<int>` for stack. Push the first vertex to the stack. Then pop one vertex, set its component to k. Push *all of its neighbours* into the stack, then delete the neighbours. In other words append the neighbours list to the stack (very fast operation). Repeat until stack is not empty.

This way we wont do infinite loop, because if we get back to the same vertex, it will have no neighbours, and we have already visited them. Therefore there is no need for the visited vector. We may set the component vectors element multiple times, but always to the same value so why check it?

However, if we do not have a visited vector, then it is harder to look for another vertex that we have not visited. Though we could look for some vertex in graph wich still has neighbours, there is a better solution.

Create `std::set<int> notvisited();` For those points that are not yet visited. At first it should contain all vertex ids, and then each time we set a component id, we attempt to remove a vertex from the `notvisited` set. We repeat getting a vertex from the set and run the fill_from() algorithm until the set becomes empty, at the same time, we have all component id-s.

**UPDATE: Using updated info on how mesh is stored.**

If you do not have equal elements in the "list of vertices" (why would you), then the index of a vertex is it's position in the array. This way, the id-s for the vertices are done.

The id-s for the triangles or faces, are in the "list of indices", let me name this array to `int listOfIndices[];`, for the j th face, the vertices connected to it are `listOfIndices[3*j + 0]`, `listOfIndices[3*j + 1]` and `listOfIndices[3*j + 2]`. To make the first vector then you have to do the following:

```
std::vector<int> vertexToFace(num_of_verteces); //previously n
for(int j = 0; j < num_of_faces; ++j)
{
    vertexToFace[listOfIndices[3*j + 0]]=j;
    vertexToFace[listOfIndices[3*j + 1]]=j;
    vertexToFace[listOfIndices[3*j + 2]]=j;
}
```

(Algorithm for building an inverse relation); Note, that in this case, you do not even need a different `faceToVertex` array, because you already have it(`listOfIndices`), you just have to index it differently (divide by 3 each time).

Comment: This doesn't help him find the pixel value of a given face.

Comment: @cmbasnett You are refferring to "I have no doubts about how to store and pass this value to a shader or whatever, the doubt is how to know the "region" to which the vertex belongs, or ultimately, the pixel." And in my answer for a given vertex id, there is a component id, which he already knows how to pass to the shader.

Comment: this seems what i need but, how can a i get the first "face" value "The vertexToFace[i]==j means i th vertex is on face j."? The UV comparsion to get the face is what I'm doing wrong in my first try I think.

Comment: @Gallo I do not know how do you display the geometry. For example if you use GL_TRIANGLES, and no index buffer, then every 3 vertices form (exactly) one triangle. In this case you have an array all vertexes `Vertex *vertarr;` which goes to your Vertex Array Buffer (VBO for short), and in that array the k th vertex is on face floor(k/3). (`Vertex` is some struct containing position, normal, uv, ect.) So, the m th triangle consists of the `arr[3*m]`, `arr[3*m+1]`, `arr[3*m+2]` vertexes.

Comment: @Gallo If you update your question with information about the the storage and display mode of the mesh, i will update my answer accordingly. (Just let me know if you do so :) )

Comment: @CsabaBálint Updated with information about the mesh data.

Comment: @Gallo Updated my answer. Feel free to suggest edit.

Comment: @CsabaBálint I updated the question with some results following your instructions, clearly I'm missing something. Recursion is not an option due to stack overflow.

Comment: @Gallo Your code looks good! I think you should use [splice_after](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/splice_after/), because merge is for sorted lists (and slower). I think they should be copied and it should work anyway, I will try your code tomorrow, until then try using splice_after :)

Comment: @Gallo Also, try printing out the whole graph. Different k-s suggest that each vertex only has 3 neighbours, they should be having a lot more.

Comment: What I see is that UVs are not playing any role to determine faces, just the indices, and those indices are for vertex positions, so even if the depth-first search works ok, all regionId will have the same value cause all mesh vertex positions are connected. My parser is serving me the UVs just to iterate it and fullfill the Vertex array, so, I need the original UV indices.

Comment: @Gallo Do you have multiple UVs for a single vertex? I might be missing something. Do you have duplicate vertexes with different UVs?

Comment: @Gallo If there are vertices only different in their UVs, so their position is the same, and you get a picture as above when you unwrap it, it may seem like a connected mesh, but it is not. Thinking indirectly, you are saying there is a path from one connected group to another through the vertices, so let's assume this. Two vertices are neighbours if, and only if there is a triangle in which both vertices appear.

Comment: It must mean, that there is a triangle which has one vertex in the first connected group, and another in the other group (and a third somewhere), otherwise, there would be no path leading from one connected group to the other, which we have assumed. That triangle though would render the two unconnected shapes connected, so we have come to a contradiction.

Comment: Note, the proof above assumes that if two vertex has the same position their UVs are different.